# How to get Saxon/XSL to leave HTML-encoded entities alone?

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I have a source XML file that has chunks of text with carriage returns and other special characters encoded into the file; for example:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<library>
  <book>
    <phrase>&quot;This isn&apos;t&#10;a&#10;big deal.&quot;</phrase>
  </book>
</library>
```

Running just a simple identity transform on that file through Saxon results in the characters that are valid in XML to be put back to their "real" form:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<library>
  <book>
    <phrase>&quot;This isn't
a
big deal.&quot;</phrase>
  </book>
</library>
```

That's valid XML, but the downstream tools are expecting `&#10;` to be in the text sent to them. Is there a way to flag/configure Saxon (or the XSL transform itself) to leave even the safe/valid escape sequences alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saxon uses an XML parser to parse your input XML into a tree of nodes where the character data is then part of a text node containing Unicode characters so it does not know nor can it distinguish whether the input had `&apos;` or `'` or a numeric character reference, the XML parser just parses that into characters.

[LexEv by Andrew Welch](http://andrewjwelch.com/lexev/) might help to preprocess the XML so that entity or character reference are converted into markup you can then transform back into the lexical format you want.

Comment: Even better: fix the downstream tools. If an XML application expects a newline to be represented as `&#10;`, then it is badly broken. If you have an electrical socket that won't take standard plugs, then bending the plugs to fit in the socket is not the right approach.